# Django Rest Framework query with uid (username, userId)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-rest-framework

I'm building an app with Django Rest framework.

Here is my Django model:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    uid = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='locations', unique=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    area = models.IntegerField(choices=AREA, default=0)
    address = models.TextField(max_length=150)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created_at',)
        verbose_name = 'Location'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Locations'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.area
```

My serializer:

```
class LocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')

    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = '__all__'
```

My view:

```
class LocationViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    This viewset automatically provides `list` and `detail` actions.
    """
    queryset = Location.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LocationSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, permissions.IsAdminUser,)
```

My routes are registered using `router.register`

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'locations', views.LocationViewSet)
```

When I query like this: `localhost:8000/locations/<locationId>` I get result of particular location matching location id. But I want to query with username/id like this:
`localhost:8000/locations/<username/uid>` . How can I accomplish this?

P.S.: I'm new to Django.

Comment: If you want to work `locations/<location_id>`, `locations/<username>`, `locations/uid` than you have poor API design. Resource should have just one id. Use query params `locations?user_id=<user_id>` or make other resource `location/user/<user_id>`. [This link](http://restful-api-design.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resources.html) can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can override `.get_queryset()` to deal with URLs such as http://example.com/api/purchases?username=denvercoder9, and filter the queryset only if the username parameter is included in the URL:

```
class PurchaseList(generics.ListAPIView):
serializer_class = PurchaseSerializer

def get_queryset(self):
    """
    Optionally restricts the returned purchases to a given user,
    by filtering against a `username` query parameter in the URL.
    """
    queryset = Purchase.objects.all()
    username = self.request.query_params.get('username', None)
    if username is not None:
        queryset = queryset.filter(purchaser__username=username)
    return queryset
```

From [Django REST framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-query-parameters) Docs